# Enter deleting StyledText in TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a strange problem.

I'm using a `StyledText` in a `TitleAreaDialog` but when I press enter to confirm the Dialog (instead of clicking with the mouse on OK) the content of the textbox disappears.

I've bound this `Listener`. Does it maybe have to do something with that?

With a regular SWT `Text` it works fine but I need the caret offset.

```
attributeName = new StyledText(container, SWT.BORDER);
attributeName.setText("EXTN_");
attributeName.setLayoutData(gridData);
attributeName.setCaretOffset(5);
attributeName.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {           
        if(!(attributeName.getText().startsWith("EXTN_"))){
            attributeName.setText("EXTN_");
            attributeName.setCaretOffset(5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
});
```

Any ideas? I'm confused.

Comment: What do you mean by: _"it works fine but I need the caret offset."_?

Comment: If I use the SWT Text Widget instead of the StyledText pressing "Enter" works fine and there's no bug.

Comment: I understood that part. What about the caret?

Comment: The only reason I use the StyledText is that I need the setCaretOffset method - otherwise I would use a basic SWT Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer the question why `Enter` does not work. But why not use `Text` and instead of `StyledText` and instead of `setCaretOffset(5)` call `text.setSelection(5, 5)`?

Comment: Well, It's not answering my question but it does exactly what I've needed the StyledText for so it's fine :)